# Multiple UIViews in animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I'm trying to create sort of a slide-out slide-in motion for my views when the user presses the forward or backwards button.
I made the first view slide out just fine, but the second one just won't slide in.

Here's my code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.1];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];

UIView *currentView = [[contentScrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
currentView.center = CGPointMake(contentScrollView.frame.size.width+contentScrollView.frame.size.width/2, currentView.center.y);

UIView *newView = [[contentScrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:1];
newView.center = CGPointMake(newView.center.x+newView.frame.size.width, newView.center.y);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I don't really see what the problem is, it should work. But the currentView just slides out, and the newView is still out in the -x values, hidden from the user.

I already tried changing to transformations, but that didn't do anything.

What could cause this?

Comment: did you try to log `newView.center.x + newView.frame.size.width`? Does it have the right value in it?

Comment: Do you want this to be simultaneous?

Comment: I want them to happen simultaneously, yes. Slide out and slide in, same time. Like when changing pages in dashboard.
It doesn't really matter what X value i put in, it just doesn't move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code (tested):
Copy and paste it to see it in action and adjust the frames for your views to suit your needs.

```
UIView *viewOne = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){{0, 0}, 200, 200}]; //currentView
UIView *viewTwo = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){{200, 0}, 200, 200}]; //newView
viewOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
viewTwo.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
[self addSubview:viewOne];
[self addSubview:viewTwo];

[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^
 {
     viewOne.frame = (CGRect){{300, 0}, 200, 200};
     viewTwo.frame = (CGRect){{-100, 0}, 200, 200};

 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


 }];
```

This is to show you how these two view sliding in and out.
You have to adjust the frames for your views accordingly to your needs.

Comment: That seems to work, I'll just try implementing it into the code the way I need it.
I'll come back later with answers, but thanks! :-)

Comment: If it helps, mark it as correct answer. Please feel free to post back should you need more help.